# Maven usage of google api

Tags: java, maven, google-api-java-client

I'm using the google calendar java API for a project.

The calendar part is fine, maven seems to download it and use it without any hassle.

My problem comes from the main dependency of this lib: the com.google.api.client api.

In particular, when I follow the instructions detailed at [this page](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup#google-api-client), maven can't compile my project properly:

```
package com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2 does not exist
package com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2 does not exist
package com.google.api.client.json.jackson2 does not exist
```

It lacks several classes and thus can't compile the file while when I download the zip and add the .jar manually without using maven it works fine.

It's the first project I manage with maven and don't know how to go from there. Pointers would be appreciated.

edit post request --- here is my POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>fr.univnantes.atal.atcal</groupId>
  <artifactId>AtCal</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>AtCal</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>google-api-services</id>
      <url>http://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/mavenrepo</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.12.0-beta</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-calendar</artifactId>
      <version>v3-rev20-1.12.0-beta</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <!-- best lock down version of the plugin too -->
      <configuration>
        <source>1.5</source>
        <target>1.5</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

I basicly added two dependencies: calendar and api client. It was the mentionned step to get things working on the doc.

Comment: Maven doesn't compile anything, the maven-compiler plugin does. You're likely missing some dependencies - post your POM, your maven commandline used and more of the maven trace, please.

Comment: done. (I tried adding the oauth library, for example, but to no avail.)

Comment: Could you try using the "official" googlecode repo instead: `https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/`

Comment: no change. What would be the correct way to add them locally under maven management?

Comment: Have you figured out which artifact(s) contain the missing packages? You should add them as dependencies in the POM if the google-api-client doesn't name them. Post your `maven package` output or link to it.

Comment: and if I name them it'll still find them on the repo?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems that the seemingly *very* beta-ish `google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev20-1.12.0-beta` isn't pushed to the sontaype repository yet, but if you try to include both the recommended repo and the one mentioned under the Calendar API in your POM:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>google-api-services</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>google-api-services-beta</id>
        <url>http://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/mavenrepo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Also, the following additional dependencies seem to be necessary:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client-java6</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.0-beta</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.0-beta</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.0-beta</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't change anything for me. Is there a special manipulation to perform so that maven correctly reconsiders all the dependencies?

Comment: Try deleting or renaming your .m2 directory and re-run mvn. Sometimes a bad POM can wreak havoc...

Comment: arghz, still nothing (well, nothing = the same classes not found). :(

Comment: I added a few deps that probably really should be transient, but aren't... Hope that brings you home.

Comment: yup sorry I didn't report here yet but I got helped on IRC and those deps came about. Thanks a lot for the help, it's very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I had adventure with google custom search api. Most of the problem were due to unavailability of mvn repo http://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/mavenrepo.

Custom search jar I took from:

```
<repository>
  <id>google-api-services</id>
  <url>http://mavenrepo.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg</url>
</repository>
```

It was in pom inside the jar downloaded manually. Newest [google-api-client](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3a%22com.google.api-client%22) and [google-http-client-jackson](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cgoogle%20jackson) (at 1.13.2-beta JacksonFactory is an additional dependency) were in central maven repo.

Comment: Thank you! I've been searching for JacksonFactory all day.

Answer (score 0):

As of a few months ago, Google started pushing libraries to the Sonatype repo. You no longer should include a repository entry in your pom.xml pointing to `google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/mavenrepo` or `mavenrepo.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com`

Doing that slows down your builds because you end up checking for all dependencies (even non Google ones) at that repository. These checks 404, then you check the master repository.